# How to check if user pressed the cross in top right corner in QMessageBox?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, pyqt5, qmessagebox

```
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question) 
            # msgBox.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("whatsapp-logo.png"))
            msgBox.setText("Do you want to add more items?")  # set text   
            msgBox.setWindowTitle("Add more items")  
            msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No) 
            path="Purchasing_Order_"+str(pdf_vendorName)+"_"+str(pdf_contact)+'.pdf'

            returnValue = msgBox.exec()
            if returnValue == QMessageBox.Yes:
                    do this
            
            elif returnValue == QMessageBox.No:
                    generate_purchase_reciept(pdf_dataframe,multi_item_df)
                    do this
                    try:
                            msgBox = QMessageBox()
                            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question) 
                            msgBox.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("whatsapp-logo.png"))
                            msgBox.setText("Do you want to send this bill to Client's WhatsApp?")  # set text   
                            msgBox.setWindowTitle("WhatsApp Message Send Option")  
                            msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
                            returnValue = msgBox.exec()
                            path="Purchasing_Order_"+str(pdf_vendorName)+"_"+str(pdf_contact)+'.pdf'
                            if returnValue == QMessageBox.Ok:
                                  do this

                    except:
                           do this

                    from MainPage import Ui_Form2
                    Form.close()
                    from MainPage import Ui_Form2 
                    self.MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
                    self.mainpage= Ui_Form2() # close after no
                    self.mainpage.setupUi(self.MainWindow)
                    self.MainWindow.show()
```

This is the code. I want to check whether user pressed the cross in the top right corner.

```
            elif returnValue == QMessageBox.Rejected:
# Handling when the message box is closed without making a choice or the cross button is 
                    print("Message box closed without making a choice")
```

This is the addition I made. However, this block is never checked even when cross is clicked. The No block always runs.

Comment: create a [mre].

Comment: The [`exec()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#exec) documentation of QMessageBox is quite clear: "When using a QMessageBox with standard buttons, this function returns a StandardButton value indicating the standard button that was clicked." The `Yes` Standard Button results in an `AcceptRole`: logic dictates that you should *first* check any result that is *not* that `Yes` button, otherwise the assumption is that clicking the "close" button results in any `RejectRole`, or, to be precise, anything else would be valid *except* for that reject role.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just use `else:` instead of `elif returnValue == QMessageBox.Rejected:`. Clicking the title-bar close button is effectively the same as cancel. There's no need to check for any specific return value other than `Ok`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `returnValue = msgBox.exec()` you can do `msgBox.open()` and connect to the `msgBox.finished` signal.
That will give you the `int` value of the button that was clicked ([ButtonRole](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmessagebox.html#StandardButton-enum))
Yes: 16384
No: 65536
and closing the window NoButton = 0